# How to extract sub string by defining before and after delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, python-re

I have data frame which contains the URLs and I want to extract something in between.

```
df
    URL
    https://storage.com/vision/Glass2020/2020-02-04_B8I8FZHl-xJ_2236301468348443721.jpg
    https://storage.com/vision/Carpet5020/2020-02-04_B8I8FZHl-xJ_2236301468348443721.jpg
    https://storage.com/vision/Metal8020/2020-02-04_B8I8FZHl-xJ_2236301468348443721.jpg
```

desired output would be like this

```
            URL                                                                           Type
 https://storage.com/vision/Glass2020/2020-02-04_B8I8FZHl-xJ_2236301468348443721.jpg      Glass2020
 https://storage.com/vision/Carpet5020/2020-02-04_B8I8FZHl-xJ_2236301468348443721.jpg     Carpet5020
 https://storage.com/vision/Metal8020/2020-02-04_B8I8FZHl-xJ_2236301468348443721.jpg      Metal8020
```

I would use `df['URL'].str.extract` but to understand how to define before and after the delimiter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea is use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with select second last value by indexing:

```
df['Type'] = df['URL'].str.split('/').str[-2]
print (df)
                                                 URL        Type
0  https://storage.com/vision/Glass2020/2020-02-0...   Glass2020
1  https://storage.com/vision/Carpet5020/2020-02-...  Carpet5020
2  https://storage.com/vision/Metal8020/2020-02-0...   Metal8020
```

EDIT: For specify different values outside expected output use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['Type'] = df['URL'].str.extract('vision/(.+)/2020')
print (df)
                                                 URL        Type
0  https://storage.com/vision/Glass2020/2020-02-0...   Glass2020
1  https://storage.com/vision/Carpet5020/2020-02-...  Carpet5020
2  https://storage.com/vision/Metal8020/2020-02-0...   Metal8020
```

Comment: Nice. But that's based on the position. Is there any what to define before and after? `After: vision/  and Before should be:  /2020`

Answer (score 3):

Try `str.split`:

```
df['Type'] = df.URL.str.split('/').str[-2]
```